# Como somar dados de array em json especificado por data

Tags: php, json, array, array-multidimensional, lógica

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(10) "01/11/2015"
    ["valor"]=>
    int(50)
    ["intensidade"]=>
    float(37.5)
    ["carga"]=>
    int(35)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(10) "01/11/2015"
    ["valor"]=>
    int(52)
    ["intensidade"]=>
    float(33.8)
    ["carga"]=>
    int(60)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(10) "01/11/2015"
    ["valor"]=>
    int(25)
    ["intensidade"]=>
    float(21.75)
    ["carga"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(10) "02/11/2015"
    ["valor"]=>
    int(52)
    ["intensidade"]=>
    float(33.8)
    ["carga"]=>
    int(60)
  }
[4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(10) "02/11/2015"
    ["valor"]=>
    int(52)
    ["intensidade"]=>
    float(33.8)
    ["carga"]=>
    int(60)
  }
[5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(10) "05/11/2015"
    ["valor"]=>
    int(52)
    ["intensidade"]=>
    float(33.8)
    ["carga"]=>
    int(60)
  }
}
```

Então, eu tenho esse array e preciso calcular os dados de mesma data e dividir pelo tanto de vezes que ele aparece, após isso preciso gerar novamente o array com os novos dados.

Comment: E o que tentou fazer até aqui?

Comment: Bom, tudo isso estava em um array só, usei o foreach para quebrar e identificar cada array, depois tentei fazer algumas coisas e nada deu certo.

Comment: Eu sei que preciso fazer no final um array contendo 3 arrays dentro cada um com sua data.

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o contexto do seu problema. Seu array vem de algum lugar, onde? A forma que você expõe sua dúvida pode te ajudar muito a conseguir boas respostas. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para deixá-la mas clara depois de ler [ask] e o [tour].

Comment: A pergunta está bem explicativa, eu tenho um array, esse array vem do banco de dados, eu estou puxando esse valores, porém algumas vezes há dados iguais em questão da data, eu preciso somente somar elas pois esses valores são colocados em um gráfico, e está aparecendo várias vezes o mesmo dia.

Comment: Seu ultimo comentário dá um contexto bem importante a sua pergunta que não está no corpo dela: os dados vem do banco de dados. Você pode fazer diretamente a média por data na sua query, eliminando o passo extra de ter que tratar isso na aplicação. Se o seu array viesse de um webservice onde você não consegue fazer isso, ai sim seria uma outra abordagem. Entendeu o que quero dizer sobre a falta de contexto na pergunta?

Comment: Não, não pode ser feito isso, pois tudo os dados que estão vindo de lá já estão filtrados e feito as contas.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arrays)-1; $i++) {
    for ($j=1; $j < sizeof($arrays); $j++) { 
        if( ($arrays[$i]['data'] === $arrays[$j]['data']) &&  !isset($arrays[$i]['sum'])  && !isset($arrays[$j]['sum']) ){
            if($i != $j){
                $arrays[$i]['valor'] += $arrays[$j]['valor'];
                $arrays[$i]['intensidade'] += $arrays[$j]['intensidade'];
                $arrays[$i]['carga'] += $arrays[$j]['carga'];   
                $arrays[$j]['sum'] = true;
                $delete[] = $j;
            }
        }
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($delete); $i++) {
    unset($arrays[$delete[$i]]);
}
```

Onde `$arrays` é o seu *array*. Obs: não é a solução perfeita mais te da um norte.